# Creating instance with methods in C++ and passing it to Python

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I'm trying to create an instance of `Game`, pass it into the main namespace of the test.py as the variable `game`, then call `game.add(e)` to run the C++ function that will add Entity `e` into the std::vector. However, this code produces the error:

`unbound method Boost.Python.function object must be called with Game instance as first argument (got Entity instance instead)`

(Some context: I'm trying to let Python create instances that will be kept in a container for C++ to run through every tick and update. I thought I had it working a few weeks ago but I came back to it and apparently it wasn't working - I know, source control.)

```
#include <vector>

class Entity{
public:
    Entity(){}
    Entity(float x, float y){}
};

class Game{
public:
    Game();
    void add(Entity* entity);
private:
    std::vector<Entity*> objects_;
};

Game::Game(){
}

void Game::add(Entity* entity){
    objects_.push_back(entity);
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include "Game.h"
#include "Entity.h"
using namespace boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(sfgame){
    class_<Game>("Game")
        .def("add", &Game::add)
        ;
    class_<Entity>("Entity", init<float, float>())
        ;
}

int main(){
    PyImport_AppendInittab("sfgame", &initsfgame);
    Py_Initialize();

    object main_module = import("__main__");
    object main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");

    import("sfgame");
    Game* game = new Game();

    try{
        main_namespace["game"] = ptr(game);
        exec_file("test.py", main_namespace);
    }
    catch (const boost::python::error_already_set &){
        PyObject *ptype, *pvalue, *ptraceback;
        PyErr_Fetch(&ptype, &pvalue, &ptraceback);
        std::string error;
        error = boost::python::extract<std::string>(pvalue);
        std::cout << error << std::endl;
    }

    delete game;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

test.py:

```
from sfgame import *

e = Entity(5,5)
game.add(e)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would receive that error if you set the variable name in the main namespace to `Game`, as it would be the same as the class name.

However, the code posted is correct. You must have compiled the .pyd file using the variable `Game`, realised your error, then changed it to `game` and compiled the C++ file to test it without recompiling the .pyd file so the error remained.